# What is Use of dropdown-toggle class in dropdown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Please help me to understand the use of "dropdown-toggle" class in dropdown. In the code below, I have removed the "dropdown-toggle" class. Without this also dropdown is working fine. Then What is use of this class.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  <div class="dropdown">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="dropdown">MENU</button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li>ITEM-1</li>
          <li>ITEM-1</li>
          <li>ITEM-1</li>
          <li>ITEM-1</li>

        </ul>  

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `dropdown-toggle` class adds the `outline: 0;` on `:focus` to the button, so when you click on the button it will not have the surrounding blue border of the "active" element.

Look on the the sample example below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Dropdowns</h2>
  <p>The .divider class is used to separate links inside the dropdown menu with a thin horizontal line:</p>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Tutorials - no border
      <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Dropdowns</h2>
  <p>The .divider class is used to separate links inside the dropdown menu with a thin horizontal line:</p>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Tutorials - with border
      <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```